# Is there any instruction which can compare float value to check if it is greater than an integer value in mips

Tags: assembly, while-loop, mips

I tried many instruction to check whether the float value enter my the user must be less than 4 but i could find any instruction . Can anybody would like to help me ?

Comment: Just store your `4` as float too or convert from integer.

Comment: Consult _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.

Answer (score 2):

> i could find any instruction

No wonder:

Many "real" MIPS CPUs (the type you found in WLAN routers 5 years ago) don't have hardware support for floating point.

(Most simulators seem to have floating point support however floating point instructions are often not mentioned in instruction set references; this is not only the case for MIPS instruction set references but also for many different architectures.)

Up to the 1990s it was normal that even desktop PCs did not have hardware support for floating-point. Today this is still true for some mobile devices.

Such devices have to perform floating-point operations using integer operations:

Example: You multiply two floating-point numbers by adding the exponent and multiplying the mantissa. (Note that multiplication is an easy operation; addition is way more complicated.)

MIPS CPUs that support floating point in hardware have the `CVT` instruction for converting an integer to a floating-point value, the `C` instruction for comparing two floating point values and the `BC1*` instructions (such as `BC1TL`) to branch if the comparison result was "true".

> Just store your `4` as float too ... – Jester

Even if you don't have floating point instructions this can help you:

Unless a number is a "Nan" or "Inf" value there are only two operations for IEEE floating point numbers which can be done easier using integer operations than multiplication: Comparison and negation!

For comparing floating-point numbers using integer instructions you need to know the following properties:

- The uppermost digit is the (negative) sign (just like for signed integers)

  (Note that zero can be stored as "+0" and as "-0".)
- If two numbers have the same sign the representing integer values can be compared with an integer operation.

  The larger integer represents the floating point number with the larger *absolute* value (so for negative values the larger integer represents the smaller floating point value)

If you want to compare a floating point value against `4.0` you first check the upper bit of the number; if it is negative the floating point number is negative and therefore less than `+4.0`, of course.

The 32-bit floating point number `4.0` is represented by the integer `0x40800000`. You compare the positive integer value representing your floating point value by this integer to find out if it is larger or smaller than `4.0`.

Example: The number `3.5` is represented by the integer `0x40600000`, the number `4.5` is represented by the integer `0x40900000`.

If you work with 64-bit floating point numbers `4.0` is represented by the 64-bit integer `0x4010000000000000` which must be processed as two 32-bit integers (`0x40100000` and `0x00000000`) when using 32-bit CPUs...

Comment: _"I think emulators like SPIM or MARS don't have either."_ PCSpim, QtSpim and MARS all support floating-point instructions.